# Issue related to "Build an Image" Task in VSTS

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-pipelines-build-task

Am working with VSTS Build Task which is related to ASP.NET Core Web Application project using docker. In that, I have added the Image Build task to create and build my Docker Image. But, am getting an issue here related to output:

> ProcessUtilityVMImage
>   C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\d9f54fb7597419f7888e5bad571c37a06a846043d81631009f726eb0bc56d7d8\UtilityVM:
>   The system cannot find the path specified.

For that I reffered following [link](https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/3413) and checked my Docker Version in my PC also, Its showing the following output.

[image]

So can you please suggest me, how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you check the docker version **on the build server**? Your PC has nothing to do with build issues, unless your PC happens to also be your build server.

Comment: Do you use private build agent? What's the result if call docker command to build image? (docker build)

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I tried to build with my Local Agent, but still am getting the same issue like " ##[error]C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe failed with return code: 1"

Comment: So, the issue is related to your environment, what's the result if you upgrade or re-install docker? On the other hand, you may setup another environment or use hosted agent instead.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT I re-installed my docker.Now, am getting "Access Denied" as error

Comment: @DanielMann My build server docker version is 0 in VSTS task

Comment: Do you mean you get access denied error when call docker build command after re-installing the docker? Can you setup a new environment?